# ¿Como puedo hacer modificaciones en un hash?

Tags: java, hash

Estoy haciendo una opcion que deja modificar el nombre dentro de mi hash pero hasta ahora no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, el codigo est de esta manera:

```
String nombre, curp;
    Hashtable<String, String> datosCliente = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

Aqui esta la opcion que cree para poder insertar datos

```
case 1:
                System.out.println("Digite el curp: ");
                curp =entrada.next();

                System.out.println("Digite el nombre:");
                nombre = entrada.next();

                datosCliente.put(curp,nombre);
```

asi me queda el dato que cree

```
{cup2=jhair}
```

pero ahora lo que deseo hacer es modificar el nombre, alguna recomendación que me puedan dar para poder implementarlo

Comment: Si lo que quieres es simplemente actualizar el nombre para un `curp` simplemente utiliza el método `put` tal y como lo estás haciendo. Este método inserta un nuevo elemento si la key no existe o lo actualiza si ya existe.

Comment: Quieres cambiar el key de la entrada? Digamos, que sea `cup3-jhair` ?